# Error using codesign: errSecInternalComponent

Tags: macos, code-signing

I'm trying to code sign a dmg file using:

```
codesign --force --sign <identity> <path-to-disk-image>
```

but it's not working, I get:

```
myDiskImAGE.dmg: errSecInternalComponent
```

what does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the full path to the disk image solved it for me, hope this helps others.